# Having trouble building pynacl

Tags: python, nacl-cryptography

I've been trying to build pynacl (https://github.com/pyca/pynacl). But I'm having some trouble. I'm running ubuntu and I've tried installing libsodium and everything else I can think of but still same problem.

When I run: `python setup.py install` i get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 202, in <module>
    name=nacl.__title__,
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute '__title__'
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong? ps I'm pretty new to python

update:
I'm running Python 2.7.5+

Comment: Can you provide more information? Which python version are you using? Are you using virtualenv? Do you have another nacl module/package somewhere in your pythonpath?

Comment: I'm running python 2.7.5+, I don't know what virtualenv is so probably not :) "nacl module/package somewhere in your pythonpath", how do I check that?

Comment: You can try to import the module in a python shell: 
>>> import nacl
>>> nacl.__title__
'PyNaCl'
>>> nacl.__path__

Comment: I can importet, I did "import nacl"

Comment: So probably you have it already installed somehow, try to print nacl.__path__ to see where it is.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute '__path__'

Comment: Do you have a file named nacl.py by chance?

Comment: no nothing like that, this seems to be a hard problem

Answer (score 0):

I went to /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ and deleted everything that had nacl in it. Now it works!